# Wordpress permalink redirect rule

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, redirect, permalinks

Running into a little bit of an issue with Wordpress permalink redirects that I was hoping I could get some help with.

Previously, I utilized the following permalink structure for my blog posts:

```
/blog/%year%/%monthnum%/ %day%/%postname%/
```

I've recently changed it to:

```
/blog/%postname%/
```

Problem is, none of my old links which were structured using the old format now work!

I know it's possible to write a general .htaccess 301 redirect rule, but besides knowing that it's possible, I don't actually know how to do it.

Any tips?

Answer (score 1):

This will strip out any number/number/number/ formatting from the url

```
RewriteRule ^blog/([0-9]+/){3}(.*) /blog/$2 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: you can also use \d in place of [0-9] but I changed it because SO was coloring the code funny even though the / in the matching group doesnt need escaping... weird

Answer (score 0):

WordPress should recognize the old permalinks by default. You should try hitting `Dashboard > Settings > Permalinks > Save changes` one more time.

In case it doesn't work, the regex your're asking for would be something like this, removing 4 digits, a slash, 2 more digits, another slash, yet 2 more digits and one last slash from the URL:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^blog/[0-9]{4}/[0-9]{2}/[0-9]{2}/(.*)$ http://example.com/blog/$1
```

Comment: you would want to use $1 not %1, % is for matches in a rewrite condition